# Does WordPress have something like timer hook?

Tags: plugin-development, hooks, actions

Are there some timer hooks to trigger event like this?

```
add_action("one_min_timer", "my_handler");
function my_handler() {
   //checking something every 1 min
}
```

Comment: yes, read this : https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_event

Comment: However wp_schedule_event works only when somebody is on website. If there is no one for hour "timer hook" doesn't work.

Comment: @Tomve Why WP doesn't provide a real timer regardless if someone visit site? I hope to execute a background job. There is any workaround?

Comment: @KyL, you need to OS related cron jobs for such cases.

Comment: @Tomve About `wp_schedule_event` I have a question. When visiting wordpress, web server forks a child process to deal with new request.  Which processes' `wp_schedule_event` will be triggered, parent process or child process?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the native PHP sleep() function in WordPress for timers in seconds, or usleep() for timers in microseconds:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.usleep.php

Comment: I think without thread, sleep will hang up whole website. And pthread of PHP needs extension module.

Comment: @KyL You could also use a cron job :)